# How to Spool file if only data exists in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am using the below script for generating the csv files. If the script runs and get the result we are writing into the CSV file along with column headers. If we do not get any result only headers are being written into CSV file. I wanted not to write any thing into CSV file if we do not get any result.
How to implement that in below script file ?

Script

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET SQLFORMAT csv;

spool status.csv;

select 
    batch_id,   
    batch_type,
    bu_code,
    bu_type,
    status,
    error_text,
    cre_user_id,
    to_char(upd_dtime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS AM') as upd_dtime,
    to_char(status_created_dtime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS AM') as status_created_dtime,
    to_char(status_queued_dtime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS AM') as status_queued_dtime,
    to_char(status_running_dtime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS AM') as status_running_dtime     
 from cox_item;

 spool off;

disconnect;

exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

- declare a variable
- check whether something exists in a table and put the result into that variable
- use it (the variable) in `where` clause

Something like this: I'd like to spool contents of these two tables; one contains rows, another doesn't:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL> select * from cars;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Your script (I saved it as `p.sql`)

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET SQLFORMAT csv;

spool status.txt;

var l_cnt number;

exec select max(1) into :l_cnt from dual where exists (select null from dept);

select *
from dept
where :l_cnt = 1;



exec select max(1) into :l_cnt from dual where exists (select null from cars);

select *
from cars
where :l_cnt = 1;

spool off;
```

Execution & result:

```
SQL> @p
SQL> $type status.txt

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me; the first table is here, another one isn't (not even its header).

Comment: Hi, my question is if table exists and query does not give any result then we should not write anything into csv file

Comment: That's a good technique for lots of situations - basically performing an IF statement in a tool that doesn't have the usual programming constructs.

Answer (score 0):

When record found, both spool sql and data file gets generated

    `set feedback off termout on autoprint on serverout on echo off  head off pages 0 newp 0
    host del c:\sql\01.txt 
    spool c:\sql\01.sql
        select 
          ' set head on newp 0 termout on autoprint on serverout on echo off '
            ||chr(10)
            ||'spool c:\sql\01.txt ' 
            || chr(10)
            || 'select  1,2,3,4,5 from user_tables where rownum<10 ;' 
            || chr(10)
            || 'spool off ' 
            from  dual 
            where exists 
            (select  1,2,3,4,5 from user_tables where rownum<10 );
    spool off;
    @c:\sql\01.sql
    /`

When no record found, spool sql file wil be empty and no data file will be generated/spooled

`set feedback off termout on autoprint on serverout on echo off  head off pages 0 newp 0
    host del c:\sql\01.txt 
    spool c:\sql\01.sql
        select 
          ' set head on newp 0 termout on autoprint on serverout on echo off '
            ||chr(10)
            ||'spool c:\sql\01.txt ' 
            || chr(10)
            || 'select  1,2,3,4,5 from user_tables where rownum<10 ;' 
            || chr(10)
            || 'spool off ' 
            from  dual 
            where exists 
            (select  1,2,3,4,5 from user_tables where rownum<10 and 1=2 );
    spool off;
    @c:\sql\01.sql
/`